# How to record an application int variable in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating a clone attack approach, and I have a variable of type int that I want to record its value in results, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `finish()` function, just add the following line :

```
recordScalar("#yourVariable", yourVariable);
```